# How to convert integer to string in C?

Tags: c, string, integer, type-conversion

I tried this example:

```
/* itoa example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    int i;
    char buffer [33];
    printf ("Enter a number: ");
    scanf ("%d",&i);
    itoa (i,buffer,10);
    printf ("decimal: %s\n",buffer);
    itoa (i,buffer,16);
    printf ("hexadecimal: %s\n",buffer);
    itoa (i,buffer,2);
    printf ("binary: %s\n",buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

but the example there doesn't work (it says the function `itoa` doesn't exist).

Comment: You should give more information, like the *exact* error message, what compiler you're using, and what OS.

Comment: [my-itoa](http://code.google.com/p/my-itoa/) was already suggested somewhere else on SO.

Answer (score 304, accepted):

Use [`sprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

```
int someInt = 368;
char str[12];
sprintf(str, "%d", someInt);
```

All numbers that are representable by `int` will fit in a 12-char-array without overflow, unless your compiler is somehow using more than 32-bits for `int`. When using numbers with greater bitsize, e.g. `long` with most 64-bit compilers, you need to increase the array size—at least 21 characters for 64-bit types.

Comment: I tried running this program, and I got a runtime error. How can I get it to work properly? http://ideone.com/Xl21B4

Comment: @AndersonGreen The code here is correct. You typed it incorrectly. The error message tells you where.

Comment: `sprintf` is discussed here in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232634/simple-use-of-sprintf-c

Comment: Often it's better to use snprintf() to cover situations where you don't know how big `str` is going to be.  (eg multi-byte characters, numbers that represent counters without a limit, etc).

Answer (score 60):

Making your own `itoa` is also easy, try this :

```
char* itoa(int i, char b[]){
    char const digit[] = "0123456789";
    char* p = b;
    if(i<0){
        *p++ = '-';
        i *= -1;
    }
    int shifter = i;
    do{ //Move to where representation ends
        ++p;
        shifter = shifter/10;
    }while(shifter);
    *p = '\0';
    do{ //Move back, inserting digits as u go
        *--p = digit[i%10];
        i = i/10;
    }while(i);
    return b;
}
```

or use the standard `sprintf()` function.

Comment: To clarify: *do while* loops are used instead of *while* for when *i* is zero.

Comment: There's a bug in this code: it will fail when `i = INT_MIN` because of the `i *= -1` line.

Comment: @Max, `while` tests the condition before the loop start, `do while` tests the condition after the loop has started.

Comment: @kasrak How to deal with that case. Is  a larger type the only option?

Answer (score 50):

That's because `itoa` isn't a standard function. Try `snprintf` instead.

```
char str[LEN];
snprintf(str, LEN, "%d", 42);
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/

Comment: At least enough to hold the maximum value allowed by the integer type, I guess.

Comment: @Gabe I use `(CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) - 1) / 3 + 2`, as [caf mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8257728/226266).

Comment: you don't have to `- 1` for snprintf.

Comment: @PerJohansson That's right :-) I was thinking of `%s` for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, but `sprintf()` is better, because you don't have the unnecessary second argument.

Comment: snprintf() is safer in that you specify how much input you're taking.  Otherwise, If your string has multi-byte characters, or ends up longer than you expected due to large numbers, you can overflow your buffer and crash your program (etc).

Comment: @gone How can I ever get multibyte in that case, or is it local dependent?

Comment: You need to factor multi-byte data into the calculation of the buffer size.  Awkward, but what else can you do?