# Length of a string as string

Tags: c, string, string-length

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert integer to string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655202/how-to-convert-integer-to-string-in-c)

I would like to calculate the length of the string and pass the value to a function as a string.

```
char* s="abcd";
int i = strlen(s);
char* lengthAsString = ????(i);
```

Comment: Converting an int to a string in C has to be a duplicate question.

Comment: see an example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/

Comment: @aakash This is C++ where OP asked for C.

Comment: @Eregrith - It's Cplusplus site, but that section is the C Library and correct for a C program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char* s = "abcd";
int i = strlen(s);
char lengthAsString[50];
sprintf(lengthAsString, "%d", i);

// now you can use lengthAsString to pass it to a function
```