# How to cast an int to a char * in C?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert integer to string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655202/how-to-convert-integer-to-string-in-c)

I have a function in C which takes an int value i. I need to turn this i value into a string (char *).

Here is what I have so far:

```
char *str = (char *)i;
myfunction(str);
```

I get the error: cast to pointer from integer of different size.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `(char*)(intptr_t)i`. It probably doesn't do what you want, though.

Comment: Do you need to get a string representation of the integer?  Or does the integer actually encode the address of a string?

Comment: Well I need to print the integer character by character. Which if I send a string to myfunction this will happen.

Comment: @user92390: Printing an integer character-by-character: ```printf("%d", i);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just not valid code. Even if you resolve the compile-time error, the result will likely be some sort of memory access error at run time. The result will be a pointer to a string that you have no idea where it actually points to. And so you'll have an error when your program accesses that memory.

I'm going to speculate that what you are really looking for is a function like `itoa()`. That's the only way this would make any sense.

**Edit**

Based on a new comment, I see that you do in fact want a function like `itoa()`. Simply trying to convert the integer to a string pointer will not do what you want.

```
char buff[80];

itoa(i, buff, 10);
myfunction(buff);
```

Comment: I am not suppose to use outside functions. I need to be able to print the integer character by character

Comment: Sheesh, it's a lot of work trying to find out exactly what you are trying to do. You should've posted the code for `myfunction()`. So then I guess you'll need to write your own `itoa()` function. I've done so many times myself. But you'll need to understand the C language a little better.

Comment: sorry my apologies. myfunction(char *string) simply goes one by one through the string and prints each character

Comment: It's valid code, although results may vary, a lot.

Comment: It's not valid code to take an integer, convert it to a char *, and then expect it to point to a string version of the original integer value.