# Converting int to string without printing

Tags: string, int

I want to convert an int to a string without printing anything on my screen. For now I used sprintf, but this also printed the int to my screen.
Also itoa is not supported by my compiler so I can't use that either.

Comment: Please show your code. Usually `sprintf` does *not* "print to screen", so there must be something you added. It would also help if you add a tag for your programming language.

Answer (score -1):

I assume You use ANSI C.

You cannot use `itoa` because it's not a standard function.

`sprintf` or `snprintf` is dedicated to that.

Since You do not want to use `sprintf`, make your own `itoa` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* itoa(int i, char b[]){
    char const digit[] = "0123456789";
    char* p = b;
    if(i<0){
        *p++ = '-';
        i *= -1;
    }
    int shifter = i;
    do{ //Move to where representation ends
        ++p;
        shifter = shifter/10;
    }while(shifter);
    *p = '\0';
    do{ //Move back, inserting digits as u go
        *--p = digit[i%10];
        i = i/10;
    }while(i);
    return b;
}
```

original answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9660930/1850043)