# C convert int to string

Tags: c, printf

I am looking for a way to convert an int to a string of a given length. If the representation of the number is shorter, it should be zero-filled.

I.e., what I'd like to see:

```
snprintf(buffer, 3, "%d", 5); -> 005
snprintf(buffer, 2, "%d", 55); -> 55
```

Actually, `snprintf(buffer, 3, "%d", 5)`; just return 5 in string.

Is there a simple way to do this ?

Comment: Many answsers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655202/how-to-convert-integer-to-string-in-c

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the "field width specifier"

```
char buffer[10];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d", 5); -> "5"
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%3d", 5); -> "  5"
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%03d", 5); -> "005"
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%2d", 55); -> "55"
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%3d", 55); -> " 55"
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%03d", 55); -> "055"
```

The second argument to `snprintf()` is the maximum number of bytes to store in `buffer`.  This protects you from buffer overruns, which the older `sprintf()` (no 'n') is susceptible to.

Comment: Important note: this assumes that `buffer` is array. If it is pointer to buffer, this will not work, `sizeof` will give size of pointer (usually 4 or 8) and not size of whatever it points to.

Comment: Good point, nasty pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of `snprintf` specifies a *msximum* length. If you want to always display a certain number of digits, and pad the leading edge with zeroes, you can specify that in the format specifier.

```
sprintf(buffer, "%03d", 5); // will output "005"
```

Specifying a number before the format specifier declares a fixed length. Simply specifying a number will pad the length out with spaces, but we can pad it with zeroes by including a leading zero in the specifier.

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, using `snprintf` is still a good idea, in case `buffer` hasn't been allocated enough space. Just remember that you'll need to pass the length of the string + 1 as the second argument for `snprintf`.

Comment: It's still prudent to use `snprintf` and not `sprintf` to avoid accidental buffer overflows.

Answer (score 0):

There are all kinds of qualifiers on printf format strings.  Check out http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/printf-format-strings.html

The one that is useful in this case is "%03d", although you'll need to snprintf 4 characters (3 plus the null terminator) to correctly get 005 out of that.

Comment: Could you explain which of the modifiers the OP needs to use to solve his problem? RTFM isn't a particularly helpful answer.