# Writing an integer to stdout in text form using only write() to do writing

Tags: c, int, system-calls

I'm trying to write an integer in stdout, in text form, with only write() function and possibly while/if.

I want to write the integer out in text form, so that it's human-readable, but actually it is write out in binary form :

Here is what I tried :

main.c :

```
#include "my_put_nbr.h"
int main()
{
    my_put_nbr(43);
    return 0;
}
```

my_put_char.c :

```
#include <unistd.h>
int my_put_nbr(int nb)
{
        write(1, &nb, sizeof(nb));
        return 0;
}
```

So how can I write the integer out in text form with only write (or putchar) and conditions ?

PS : I must not use other libraries, so I can't use printf or whatever !

My github : [link](https://github.com/shark-oxi/my_functions)

`text mode` and `binary mode` are common in computer science, but here is a reminder for ones who don't understand what I mean by `text form` :

> On a UNIX system, when an application reads from a file it gets
>   exactly what's in the file on disk and the converse is true for
>   writing. The situation is different in the DOS/Windows world where a
>   file can be opened in one of two modes, binary or text. In the binary
>   mode the system behaves exactly as in UNIX. However on writing in text
>   mode, a NL (\n, ^J) is transformed into the sequence CR (\r, ^M) NL.

Quote from [Cygwin.com](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-textbinary.html)

---

MAJ :

I found the answer:

```
#include "my_putchar.h"
/* 0x2D = '-'
 * 0x0 = NUL */
int my_put_nbr(int n)
{
        if (n < 0)
        {
                my_putchar(0x2D);
                n = -n;
        }

        if (n > 9)
        {
                my_put_nbr(n/10);
        }

        my_putchar((n%10) + '0');

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your program include any header files? If yes, please post the entire program.

Comment: You must convert the `int` to decimal digits yourself.

Comment: @RSahu
: Done, I made a MAJ

Comment: So do you want to write the integer out in *text* form, so that it's human-readable, or do you want to write it out in *binary* form, with the expectation that another program will read the binary output?

Comment: @GuyHarris
I want to write the integer out in text form, so that it's human-readable ! That's exactly the thing :) But actually I think my output is binary.

Comment: @TobySpeight : please re-open, I find the answer

Comment: It's not going to be reopened until you make the question understandable in the first place.

Comment: @CareyGregory I wish it is understandable this time.

Answer (score 2):

write is writing, but it is writing non-visible characters.
You can see this with:

```
./myprogram | od -tx1
```

You will need to make the number in *n* (int value 23) into the string "23" before printing it.

One way:

```
  char buffer[16];
  snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d", n);
  write(1, buffer, strlen(buffer));
```

Comment: the number is `42`
`$ ./main.out` => output : `�Ð�` and
`$ ./main.out | od -tx1` => output : `0000053`

Comment: John Hascall
:
i don't want to use snprintf(), just write()

Comment: Then you will need to write the code to do the conversion to a string yourself.  This page should help http://stackoverflow.com/a/9660930/2040863

Comment: *i don't want to use snprintf(), just write()*  Why do you expect writing a raw binary `int` to a character-based terminal to be readable?

Comment: @AndrewHenle
I just re-coded `putchar`, `puts` and `strlen` with only write or/and boucle (while)or/and conition (if).
I now want to write a put_int with just write() and ascii translation.
I fact I want to use only system call and no additionnal library.

Comment: [Github](https://github.com/shark-oxi/my_functions) : here it is what I'm doing