# Convert int to string and concatenate the result

Tags: c, string, int, string-conversion

I try to concatenate a string with an integer converted into string and write the result into a file.

There is my code (simplified):

```
char * convert_int_string(int val)
{
  char * str = malloc(sizeof(char)*64);
  sprintf(str,"%d",val);
  return str;
}

char * parse_val(int val){
  char * str = malloc(sizeof(char)*64);
  char * str2 = convert_int_string(val);
  strcat(str, "test");
  strcat(str,str2);
  free(str2);
  return str;
}

fprintf(my_file, "%s\n", parse_val(42));
```

But I get this result and I don't understand why (here val is equal to 42):

```
��7s�test42
```

(I used this post [How do I concatenate const/literal strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/how-to-concatenate-const-literal-strings-in-c) and this one [How to convert integer to string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655202/how-to-convert-integer-to-string-in-c))

Comment: `strcat(str, "test");` --> `strcpy(str, "test");` : The memory chunk returned by `malloc` is not initialized.

Comment: `str` in `parse_val()` has been allocated memory but you cannot `concat` without initialising that memory.

Comment: Nice, thanks @BLUEPIXY. Works well

Comment: in  `strcat(str, "test");` line you concaenate allocated but uninitialized string t=with string "test". But there is some garbage data in that uninitialized memory, so you get  in resulted string part of that garbage till the first zero byte which in `C` means the end of the string

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you get garbaged output is because what you give to `strcat` is garbage. Indeed, you malloc'ed 64 bytes for `str` but you didn't initialize it, so you don't know which bytes it contains. You can either use `calloc` instead of malloc or use `memset` to put 0 in `str`.

EDIT: In fact, you only need to put \0 as the first byte of `str`. Indeed, `strcat` first looks for the \0 char in the destination string, from there it adds the second string