# How do i change an int variable to a string variable in c?

Tags: c, string, file, text, structure

You read the question I need to be able to scan a int value and print it back out as a string variable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print it back, you can use the "%d" specifier when using printf. If you want to convert the integer value to a character string for other purposes, you can use itoa.

Comment: `itoa` is not a standard function. `sprintf` or `snprintf` would be a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sprintf` function to do it.

```
int a;
// [log(2^63 - 1)] + 1  = 19 where
// [x] is the greatest integer <= x
// +1 for the terminating null byte 
char s[19+1];

// read an integer
scanf("%d", &a);

// store the integer value as a string in s
sprintf(s, "%d", a);
```

Comment: May overflow `s`, I'd highly recommend using `snprintf`. Who's to say you won't upgrade compiler at some point in future and get a 64-bit int?

Comment: @MattMcNabb updated the answer. Yes, `snprintf` is a safer option.

Answer (score 0):

YOu should use `sprintf` instead of `itoa` as it iota is not a starndard

```
int aInt;
scanf("%d", &aInt)
char str[50];
sprintf(str, "%d", aInt);
```

detail use of [sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232634/simple-use-of-sprintf-c)