# How to write floats to a C-string?

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I am new to working with arrays in C and I am trying to store a string like so:

```
//x, y, p are floats
("X: %f\nY: %f\nP: %f", x, y, p)
```

into an array.

I do not know how to read in the values `x`, `y`, `p` so that the array stores it as a single string.

Is it possible? If not, how should I do this?

**UPDATE**

So apparently people don't understand what I mean.

The above **is not my specific code**, it is the string I wish to store; an example.

```
printf("X: %f\nY: %f\nP: %f", x, y, p);
```

is equal to when printed in the command:

```
X: 10.000000
Y: 12.000000
P: 32.000000
```

This is how I wish to store it in an array, instead, it is recognising it as 4 arguments, instead of 1.

1. the string = "X: %f\nY: %f\nP: %f"
2. x
3. y
4. p

How can I make it recognise it as **one** argument?

Comment: where is the array and where is the string here?

Comment: [use sprintf?](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/?kw=sprintf) just remember to make sure the output buffer is large enough

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh FWIW: `"X: %f\nY: %f\nP: %f"` is a string and an array.  Yet in OP's case the destination string is likely implied.

Comment: None of this is valid C code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple use of sprintf c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232634/simple-use-of-sprintf-c) -- please use this link if confirming a duplicate. The previous one was very narrow and about a bug in some version of gcc

Comment: To form a right-sized buffer and print use `int n = snprintf(NULL, 0,  "X: %f\nY: %f\nP: %f", x, y, p); char buf[n+1]; snprintf(buf, sizeof buf,  "X: %f\nY: %f\nP: %f", x, y, p); `

Comment: @SouravGhosh check update

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski check the update

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I have not heard of it, wouldn't have asked otherwise. Plus the question title, and content does not make reference, so while there may be a suitable answer, it's by no means a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sprintf` or `snprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf). Here `array` is your C-string array (`char *array[n]`):

```
array[x] = malloc(64);
snprintf(array, 64, "X: %f\nY: %f\nP: %f", x, y, p);
```

`snprintf` is safer because you can set the maximum number of characters it should write.

I picked the magic number `64` here, but you should make sure to allocate enough memory to store the result string with the converted floats.

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you a million my friend. I am glad you understood what I was meaning, I copped a lot of hate on this question.